# How do I refactor these Rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following routes. I want the structure of the app to remain the same (one controller with multiple functions), but I want to make the routes file look more reasonable and easily extensible.

```
get 'splunk/ocd/:order_id' => "splunk#order_collection_details"
get 'splunk/ord/:order_id' => "splunk#order_request_details"
get 'splunk/ord_ar/:request_id' => "splunk#ord_associated_requests"
get 'splunk/ord_ad/:user_id/:deal_option_id' => "splunk#ord_additional_details"
get 'splunk/avatax_logs/:order_id' => "splunk#avatax_logs"
get 'splunk/billing_updates/:billing_record_id' => "splunk#billing_updates"
get 'splunk/cc_storage_details/:billing_record_id' => "splunk#cc_storage_details"
```

Comment: What do you mean by more reasonable and easily extensible?  What are your current pain points, as to me this looks like a pretty straightforward set of routes? Is this app already in production to where you need to maintain the current routes?

Comment: The second line of your routes will not be triggered as the first line will always catch that route.

Comment: @CarsonCole, actually, the URIs _are_ different, `ocd/` and `ord/`.

Comment: Yep, small difference. Sorry about the confusion it caused though.

Comment: @JGrubb Darn, those two look similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @MikeBrant that there doesn't really seem to be any huge need to refactor this, but if you really wanted to, I might try something like this -

```
controller :splunk do
  get 'splunk/ocd/:order_id' => :order_collection_details
  get 'splunk/ord/:order_id' => :order_request_details
  get 'splunk/ord_ar/:request_id' => :ord_associated_requests
  get 'splunk/ord_ad/:user_id/:deal_option_id' => :ord_additional_details
  get 'splunk/avatax_logs/:order_id' => :avatax_logs
  get 'splunk/billing_updates/:billing_record_id' => :billing_updates
  get 'splunk/cc_storage_details/:billing_record_id' => :cc_storage_details
end
```

It's a little more organized and easier to read, but if your whole app is going to be around one controller, I'm not sure I see the need.

Comment: Nice, this is pretty much what I was looking for. I'm guessing there is no way to get rid of the `splunk/` prefix in the url match.

Comment: for all I know, there is a way, but I'm not sure off the top of my head what it'd be.

Comment: Actually, depending on whether you want the splunk/ prefix in the URLs or not, you _could_ remove them.  The URIs would be then be `ocd/:order_od', 'avatax_logs/:order_id`, etc., and it would still map them all to the correct controller. Not sure if that's exactly what you were asking or not...

Comment: ah nice! i had to drop the leading slash in front of the namespace name, but besides that, works great.